# inner join to get data from 4 tables in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I developed an app where I send messages to customer and also to agent.
There is to table to maintain these record one is sent for customer and second is inbox for agent.
I want to listing my all sent message to customer and agent at one page.

I am getting sent to customer from this query

```
 function  getSentRecords($start, $limit,$user_id){

 $query=$this->db->query("select msg.*,cust.name from sent msg,customers cust where msg.from_id=$user_id and cust.id=msg.to_id limit $limit, $start");
 return $query->result_array();
}
```

And at other page sent to Agent from this function

```
 function  getInboxRecords($start, $limit,$user_id){

    //$user_id = $this->session->userdata('admin_id');
     $query=$this->db->query("select msg.*,cust.name from inbox msg,admin adm where    msg.to_id=$user_id and adm.id=msg.from_id limit $limit, $start");
    //$this->db->limit($limit, $start);

    return $query->result_array();
  }
```

How I can get my sent at one page to inner join please help

Answer (score 2):

You can use UNION for that:

```
$query = "
  SELECT msg.*,cust.name, 'customers' as typ FROM sent msg
      JOIN customers cust ON cust.id = msg.to_id
  where msg.to_id = $user_id

  UNION

  SELECT msg.*,cust.name, 'agent' as typ FROM inbox msg
      JOIN admin adm ON adm.id = msg.from_id
  where msg.to_id = $user_id
";
return $query->result_array();
```

You can read more about UNION in mysql [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply but I think 'a' should instead of msg. but how I will get the name of customer at customer table and the name of agent at admin panel

Comment: Its ok I gave b insted of cust. its working but getting only records from agents not from customers

Comment: Just edited my answer. If it shows records from agents it should as well with the customers as long as you have queried for an existing user_id on the customer table. Do you apply limits to your query?

Comment: Maybe its because of the limit. The query I showed you will fetch data from the first table `Agents`. If the records in the agents contains a lot more than your limit then it would only show the agents records.

Comment: Agent table contain two records and customer table contain 14 records . but this show only two records from agent not from custoerm

Comment: Thanks dear I edited at top there will be customer instead of admin at first query now this is working fine thanks

Comment: Sir can u help that how we can define that  this is sent message for customer and which one for agent. Because there is same columns  in listing.

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer please vote or accept as correct answer to your question ;)